# Passing JAAS form authentication to REST service

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jaas

I am building a struts2 web application with JAAS form authentication.  The project contains a few JSP pages and a REST service.  I have authentication working correctly for my jsp pages, but in one of my JSP pages, I am making a call to the REST service, and it seems that the authentication is not passed on to the REST service.

Here is how it works:

I navigate to my web app url localhost:8080/PersonPortal/index.jsp, which contains a couple text boxes for input and a submit button.

When I go there in my browser, it automatically redirects to my login.jsp page as expected:

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check">
user:<input type="text" name="j_username"/>
pass:<input type="text" name="j_password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

After logging in. I am taken to the index page as expected. Now the problem.  On my index page, I have a couple text boxes and submit button.  I am submitting my user input form to a struts action.  In my struts action class, I am calling my REST service:

```
//Create entity from user input
User user = new User();
user.setName(name);
user.setSsn(ssn);

//Call REST service
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/PersonPortal/api/User");
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

//get output
String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Here is the problem.  Instead of getting a proper response in the output, I am getting the HTML code of the JAAS login page.

Even tho I already authenticated when I first accessed the application in my web browser, it asks for authentication again when trying to access the REST service.  Any idea how to make it pass on the current login credentials to the REST service?

Another bit of info: After logged in, If I type the web service URL directly into the browser address bar, it will consume the service without asking for authentication, but it does ask for authentication if I call the service from the resteasy client.

Comment: You are creating your own HTTP request - without JSessionID cookie. The server can't know which session to bind that request to and thus the authentication information is not available.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Do know if there is an alternative way of calling the REST service, which could possibly maintain the session authentication?

Comment: Well I -was- wondering why you are not using the standardized JAX-RS API. Note that in my experience webservices tend to have their own isolated authentication measures in stead of being tied to a web application's session. You may want to consider some single-signon solution in stead.

Comment: Well that gives me something to think about, thanks. I am kind of new to web services.  I have a web application with no web services at the moment, and I am trying to move some of my api to web services for reusability. I am not familiar with best practices in this area, so it is a bit of a learning experience.

Comment: Check out Jersey which is the reference implementation of the JAX-RS specification/API. The API is exceptionally easy to use, you'll probably love it. https://jersey.java.net/

Comment: @Gimby Thank you. With that info, I figured out that I needed to use the  Resteasy api since I am using JBoss/Wildfly app server. It is much cleaner then how I had it before.  I still have to figure out my authentication problem tho. I don't want the application user to have to login everytime the application needs to call the REST api. Thanks for your help